# Vega Lite Custom Axis Interval Steps

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite, vega

My Chart on Vega Editor is below:

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgFgpglg5mAuIBcAmADGgNCAJAZwGNIBbAQ2XHngAc8kB6egNwhlIDoYp4wBXAI3ZQA9vUIlSzVqQC0AG24RmAVnYArPMIB2IbABMIhAE5Rq8ETqQgAggAI8UYtTkRb-UkdtEP8WwHduMFsIYn4IPQM9Wz1SeA5dEBi45FAmUjleQ2QAbVByK2sE-mQUAF9MPIoAISLkZXLKqwBhWqQAZgaQfJAAEVaARk7ugFFWgA4higAxVvqKrooAcVaATkmrAAlWgHZ1kABJVrKAXXKQMiMAawp3IwSILQJhPSgtGBSQAA8PgDMoCDkego5Gw8AAntQIBQtMJiK90glSJ8oHgPnJSGE5NY3i5kGhSmcwb9-oCbglwZCKABHXikLTmOLmFiI5GopCgcwES5NYS8ekfCCfah3KwEaByAAUkFgCHo6AAlCACWcnnJhCLQH8AUCrORlUA)

My aim to is be able to add custom interval in the Y-Axis.

I want the step to be 3. This means that the values on the Y-axis should be 0, 3, 6, 9 only.

How can I achieve this?

I tried a few Axis field like TickMinStep, tickCount, domain, range, etc. However, none of these worked to get what I wanted.

It would be desirable if the value can be controlled by param.

Answer (score 0):

Set the values option.

[image]

```
{
  "height": 200,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2},
      {"a": "B", "b": 5},
      {"a": "C", "b": 3},
      {"a": "D", "b": 1},
      {"a": "E", "b": 8},
      {"a": "F", "b": 5},
      {"a": "G", "b": 9},
      {"a": "H", "b": 7},
      {"a": "I", "b": 2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"values": {"expr": "[0,3,6,9]"}}
    },
    "color": {"field": "a"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Is there a less manual way? Like just giving the value of 3 to get these ticks. If I give the value of 2, then the values would automatically be 0,2,4,6,8,10, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The labels use some kind of heuristics to decide what to show and values is the only way to control it like you want to.