# VegaLite Y-Axis interwal value customization for maximum value

Tags: d3.js, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I have a issue that link to already ask question on stackoverflow-[reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77860219/vega-lite-custom-axis-interval-steps)

I want to know how i can set a surplus (i.e maximum value of y-axis+ some extra) so that any text label aligned on the bar top should come inside the chart
[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgFgpglg5mAuIBcAmADGgNCAJAZwGNIBbAQ2XHngAc8kB6egNwhlIDoYp4wBXAI3ZQA9vUIlSzVqQC0AG24RmAVnYArPMIB2IbABMIhAE5Rq8ETqQgAggAI8UYtTkRb-UkdtEP8WwHduMFsIYn4IPQM9Wz1SeA5dEBi45FAmUjleQ2QAbVByK2sE-mQUAF9MPIoAISLkZXLKqwBhWqQAZgaQfJAAEVaARk7ugFFWgA4higAxVvqKrooAcVaATkmrAAlWgHZ1kABJVrKAXXKQCC0CYT0oLRgUkAAPB4AzKAg5PQpybHgAT2oEAoWmExFu6QSpEeUDwDzkpDCcmsdxcyDQpQx2HhfwgRhyoDIRgA1hR3HjsBcrjc7g9nkhQG8Pl8rD8QP9AcDQeC5JDobD6SB4YjkTBUUh0Wc-q93p9SQl2UCrABHXikLTmOLmFi8mEPNIZLICiCPah4qzZLBtTAANkwK2OIAxZyucmEZoZMuZCyd80JJIFCoo8GNiGwfwA8i8XngIIgkDI5udLtdbvcAyHpUy5ZLM7KrMVfgDFSAVWqNbEoNrncJXe6QIy896MacgA)
as u define value in referece question , i want to know how i can make it dynamic any value for y-axis is come its automatically add some value in it .Any Vegalite expr or function can do this.
I tried with domainMin,domainMax but it became little bit static ,How i can achive this dynamically for y-axis.

Comment: See here and upvote for the benefit of others if you found the answers useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456476/setting-a-dynamic-domain-in-vega-lite-deneb/75456962#75456962

Comment: thanks it look like same as i am expecting