# How to customize Y-Axis scale division step in VegaLite

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I have a issue that link to already ask question on stackoverflow [Refrence question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77860219/vega-lite-custom-axis-interval-steps)

I'm working with Vega-Lite and trying to customize the y-axis interval steps to achieve a specific step size. I want the y-axis to be displayed with intervals of 10 (e.g., 0, 10, 20, 30, ...). I have attempted to use the tickMinStep property, but it doesn't seem to provide the desired output.

Comment: Please provide a full spec in the online editor to debug.